# List all ACF field values across every post on one page

Tags: php, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I used an ACF repeater field for data sheets/instruction manual download links of products in woocommerce. There's 50 products and each has 1 to 4 download links on their product page. I've been searching for a way to list all the links form all 50 products on one page the way you would query all posts on a page in a list. I don't even know where to start looking and I didn't see anything specific on the ACF forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) and [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/).

Essentially you're just looping through all your posts like normal and then adding some custom fields into it.

Be sure to reference the [Repeater Field documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/).

This should work inside a loop. Notice you'll need your post ID.

```
<ul>
    <?php

    if( have_rows('YOURREPEATERFIELDNAMEHERE', 'POSTIDHERE') ):

        while ( have_rows('YOURREPEATERFIELDNAMEHERE', 'POSTIDHERE') ) : the_row(); ?>


            <li><?php echo get_sub_field('SUBFIELDNAMEHERE'); ?></li>

       <?php endwhile;

    else :

        // no rows found

    endif;

    ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll post the result for others when I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this.

```
<?php 

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    //'orderby'         => 'title',
    //'order'           => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
        'field'            => 'slug', // Or 'term_id' or 'name'
        'terms'            =>  'winter-products' // A slug term
        // 'include_children' => false // or true (optional)
    )),
));

if( $posts ): ?>
    <h3>Winter Products</h3>
    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post );
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

    ?>


            <?php if( have_rows('extra_info', $post_id) ): ?> 
                <li>

            <strong><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong> 

                <ul>

                <?php while( have_rows('extra_info', $post_id) ): the_row(); ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_sub_field('link_title'); ?></a></li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```